# Unsupported characters in input

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I want to assign a string of characters to a variable but it says

```
: there isn't a "code to show.
```

I have a string that i want to assign to a variable

```
d="stunning:/ËstÊnÉªÅ/"
Unsupported characters in input
```

or

```
word="stuning:/ˈstraɪkɪŋ/"
Unsupported characters in input
```

so basically the interpreter doesn't allow me to assign it to a variable, so I can't code on it.

How can I extract, delete those characters from the text, or is there anything to do , so python will support this kind of input.

I've tried to converted it into others format like ansi, utf, etc. but without success.

P.S.: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: "it says"?  Please post enough code to show the error message and the actual error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the source file encoding accordingly to the actual encoding of the file, so that the interpreter knows how to parse it.

For instance, if you use UTF-8, just add this string to the header of the file:

```
    # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

It must be the first or the second line of the file. See [PEP 0263: Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: thank you. it seems that It has solved my problems for now(and hope for ever).

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint (waiting for the actual code): prepend `u` to the string to mark it as unicode.

```
u"/ËstraÉªkÉªÅ/"
```

Comment: It works for your example but doesn't for "/ˈstraɪkɪŋ/" for example. Need a general solution.