# python hashlib sha224 - Unsupported characters in input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting this if I do:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha224('Nguyễn').hexdigest()
Unsupported characters in input
```

What else do I need?

I have

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me and returns `'4d365efe76a23d118b9d8585a0a23642dd0e7d026138e1f9598ee3b7'` as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this from a file, you should add

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

as the first or second line of your file as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873927/2896874). If you need to do this from the interpreter, you're better off using Python 3 and doing

```
hashlib.sha224('Nguyễn'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Might I add, that although this has worked for your particular use case, `# encoding=utf-8` is a better alternative and works on all the different interpreters I've tried so far.

Comment: If the `-*-`...`-*.` syntax is used, [emacs will use the line as well as Python](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html)

Answer (score 3):

Its because of your IDE that doesn't has a default encoding.So you need to do it manually :

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha224(u'Nguyễn'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: ``>>> hashlib.sha224('Nguyễn'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
Unsupported characters in input`` - the same sh*

Comment: @doniyor You can also try the shebang `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

Comment: @doniyor Or just pass `u'Nguyễn'`